# Pandas extract numbers from column into new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have this df where the rect column is all strings. I need to extract the x, y, w and h from it into separate columns. The dataset is very large so I need an efficient approach

```
df['rect'].head()
0    <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>
1    <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>
2    <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>
3    <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>
4    <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>
```

So far this solution works however it's very messy as you can see

```
df[['x', 'y', 'w', 'h']] = df['rect'].str.replace('<Rect \(', '').str.replace('\),', ',').str.replace(' by ', ',').str.replace('>', '').str.split(',', n=3, expand=True)
```

Is there a better way? Possibly a regex approach

Comment: Where is that string column created?

Comment: the string column is created in other functions that I don't have access to, so I have to work from here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `extractall`

```
df[['x', 'y', 'w', 'h']] = df['rect'].str.extractall('(\d+)').unstack().loc[:,0]
Out[267]: 
match    0    1    2    3
0      120  168  260  120
1      120  168  260  120
2      120  168  260  120
3      120  168  260  120
4      120  168  260  120
```

Comment: @ksooklall yep ,happy coding

Answer (score 5):

#### Inline

Produce a copy

```
df.assign(**dict(zip('xywh', df.rect.str.findall('\d+').str)))

                          rect    x    y    w    h
0  <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>  120  168  260  120
1  <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>  120  168  260  120
2  <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>  120  168  260  120
3  <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>  120  168  260  120
4  <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>  120  168  260  120
```

Or just reassign to `df`

```
df = df.assign(**dict(zip('xywh', df.rect.str.findall('\d+').str)))

df

                          rect    x    y    w    h
0  <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>  120  168  260  120
1  <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>  120  168  260  120
2  <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>  120  168  260  120
3  <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>  120  168  260  120
4  <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>  120  168  260  120
```

---

#### Inplace

Modify existing `df`

```
df[[*'xywh']] = pd.DataFrame(df.rect.str.findall('\d+').tolist())

df

                          rect    x    y    w    h
0  <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>  120  168  260  120
1  <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>  120  168  260  120
2  <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>  120  168  260  120
3  <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>  120  168  260  120
4  <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>  120  168  260  120
```

Comment: are you sure `*` works in `df[[*'xywh']] = ...`. I keep getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: It's your version of Python.  Yes, I'm sure.  What it's doing is unpacking the string as a list.  You could do the same thing with a simple `df[list('xywh')]` or more explicitly with `df[['x', 'y', 'w', 'h']]`

Answer (score 3):

If the strings follow a specific format `<Rect \((\d+),(\d+)\),(\d+) by (\d+)>`, you can use this regular expression with `str.extract` method:

```
df[['x','y','w','h']] = df.rect.str.extract(r'<Rect \((\d+),(\d+)\),(\d+) by (\d+)>')

df
#                          rect    x    y    w    h
#0  <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>  120  168  260  120
#1  <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>  120  168  260  120
#2  <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>  120  168  260  120
#3  <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>  120  168  260  120
#4  <Rect (120,168),260 by 120>  120  168  260  120
```

Comment: `o/` @Psidom (-:

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), which extracts groups from regex into columns:

```
df['rect'].str.extract(r'\((?P<x>\d+),(?P<y>\d+)\),(?P<w>\d+) by (?P<h>\d+)', expand=True)
```

Result:

```
     x    y    w    h
0  120  168  260  120
1  120  168  260  120
2  120  168  260  120
3  120  168  260  120
4  120  168  260  120
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those cases where it makes sense to "optimize" the data itself instead of trying to morph it into what a consumer wants.  It's much easier to change clean data into a specialized format than it is to change a specialized format into something portable.

That said, if you *really* have to parse this, you can do something like

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', '<Rect (120,168),260 by 120>')
['120', '168', '260', '120']
>>>
```