# How to create separate substring column from dataframe column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have dataframe like:

```
Instru,Name
16834306,INFOSYS18SEP640.50PE
16834306,INFOSYS18SEP640.50PE
16834306,BHEL18SEP52.80CE
16834306,BHEL18SEP52.80CE
16834306,IOCL18SEP640PE
16834306,IOCL18SEP640PE
```

I want create separate column by taking string from Name Column as below:

```
Instru,Name,Symbol,Month,SP,Type
16834306,INFOSYS18SEP640.50PE,INFOSYS,18SEP,640.50,PE
16834306,INFOSYS18SEP640.50PE,INFOSYS,18SEP,640.50,PE
16834306,BHEL18SEP52.80CE,BHEL,18SEP,52.80,CE    
16834306,BHEL18SEP52.80CE,BHEL,18SEP,52.80,CE
16834306,IOCL18SEP640PE,IOCL,18SEP,640,PE
16834306,IOCL18SEP640PE,IOCL,18SEP,640,PE
```

Note: Decimal to appear as decimal and int as int for SP Column

Comment: is the structure always the same? 4 characters,5 characters, then a flota and then the last two characters?

Comment: No Sir, it may vary as per the company symbol. String before '18SEP' and after may be considered.

Comment: If you have a regex for it see answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46928636/pandas-split-list-into-columns-with-regex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas extract numbers from column into new columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52171736/pandas-extract-numbers-from-column-into-new-columns)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [**`pandas.Series.str.extract`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with named groups in regex pattern

```
pat = '(?P<Symbol>.*?)(?P<Month>\d{1,2}\w{3})(?P<SP>[\d\.]+)(?P<Type>.*)'
df.join(df.Name.str.extract(pat))

     Instru                  Name   Symbol  Month      SP Type
0  16834306  INFOSYS18SEP640.50PE  INFOSYS  18SEP  640.50   PE
1  16834306  INFOSYS18SEP640.50PE  INFOSYS  18SEP  640.50   PE
2  16834306      BHEL18SEP52.80CE     BHEL  18SEP   52.80   CE
3  16834306      BHEL18SEP52.80CE     BHEL  18SEP   52.80   CE
4  16834306        IOCL18SEP640PE     IOCL  18SEP     640   PE
5  16834306        IOCL18SEP640PE     IOCL  18SEP     640   PE
```

---

#### Explanation of the regex patter

regex is a funny fuzzy business and is an art form.  I'll explain what I did and why.  You can compare what I did relative to [@jonclements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52224260/2336654) and see that we both attacked the problem with the same approach but made subtly different assumptions.

- `'(?P<group_name>pattern)'` Is a way to create a capture group and name it with `'group_name'`
- `'(?P<Symbol>.*?)'` Grabs all characters up to the next capture group, the `'?'` says don't be greedy about it.
- `'(?P<Month>\d{1,2}\w{3})'` Grabs 1 or 2 digits then 3 letters.  The vagueness of 1 or 2 digits is why I made the prior group non-greedy.
- `'(?P<SP>[\d\.]+)'` Grab one or more digits or periods.  Admittedly, this isn't terribly graceful as it could grab `'4.2.4.5'` but it should get the job done.
- `'(?P<Type>.*)'` Plays clean up and grabs the rest.

Comment: Great answer.  It could be useful if you explained the regex patters.

Comment: @Alexander in process

Answer (score 4):

You can use `str.extract` and apply `.astype` to the result to get your desired columns and your specific numeric column as a float:

```
separated = df.Name.str.extract(r"""(?ix)
    (?P<Symbol>[a-z]+)     # all letters up to a date that matches
    (?P<Month>\d{2}\w{3})  # the date (2 numbers then 3 letters)
    (?P<SP>.*?)            # everything until the "type"
    (?P<Type>\w{2}$)       # Last two characters of string is the type
""").astype({'SP': 'float'})
```

Which'll give you:

```
    Symbol  Month     SP Type
0  INFOSYS  18SEP  640.5   PE
1  INFOSYS  18SEP  640.5   PE
2     BHEL  18SEP   52.8   CE
3     BHEL  18SEP   52.8   CE
4     IOCL  18SEP  640.0   PE
5     IOCL  18SEP  640.0   PE
```

Then apply `df.join(separated)` to get your final DF of:

```
     Instru                  Name   Symbol  Month     SP Type
0  16834306  INFOSYS18SEP640.50PE  INFOSYS  18SEP  640.5   PE
1  16834306  INFOSYS18SEP640.50PE  INFOSYS  18SEP  640.5   PE
2  16834306      BHEL18SEP52.80CE     BHEL  18SEP   52.8   CE
3  16834306      BHEL18SEP52.80CE     BHEL  18SEP   52.8   CE
4  16834306        IOCL18SEP640PE     IOCL  18SEP  640.0   PE
5  16834306        IOCL18SEP640PE     IOCL  18SEP  640.0   PE
```

Comment: I like your explanation of the regex pattern.  I'll make the same effort and contrast with yours.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your splitting function and create the desired output

```
def f(x):
    for i, c in enumerate(x):
        if c.isdigit():        
            break
    return [x[0:i], x[i:9], x[9:-2], x[-2:]]

df[['Symbol','Month','SP','Type']] = pd.DataFrame(df.Name.apply(f).tolist())

     Instru               Name Symbol  Month      SP Type
0  16834306  INFY18SEP640.50PE   INFY  18SEP  640.50   PE
1  16834306  INFY18SEP640.50PE   INFY  18SEP  640.50   PE
2  16834306   BHEL18SEP52.80CE   BHEL  18SEP   52.80   CE
3  16834306   BHEL18SEP52.80CE   BHEL  18SEP   52.80   CE
4  16834306     IOCL18SEP640PE   IOCL  18SEP     640   PE
5  16834306     IOCL18SEP640PE   IOCL  18SEP     640   PE
```